# HSQLDB SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX: Table Data is Read Only

Tags: java, oracle, junit, syntax, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB for JUnit Tests, the test data is provided by XML Files with dbUnit. Our application uses an Oracle DB in production.

In order to suppert Oracle-specific queries I have added the property sql.syntax_ora=true to the url like this:

```
db.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:unitdb;sql.syntax_ora=true
```

When I run my JUnit test I get the exception

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: The table data is read only
```

I have also tried to execute the query `SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE;`

but this gives me the same exception.

Please help me with this problem. Thanks!

Comment: What is the query you are executing?

Comment: I have to test the query `select * from (select a,b,c from myTable order by a) where rownum = 1;` . `rownum` is not supported by hsqldb, so this is why I want to execute the query `SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE;` in order to support `rownum`.

Comment: How come the error didn't occur when the data was inserted into the table? There may be something wrong with your test setup.